# Bash error "no such file or directory" when I type cd usr/bin/python3.7

Tags: command-line, bash

i tryied to install pyarrow atlink on my user file .and i use cd command to
went to python file and install pyarrow there.but i meet bash error
 lenovo@Lenovo-Y50:~$ whereis python
    python: /usr/bin/python3.7 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/python3.6 
    but when i type
    ~$ cd usr/bin/python3.7
    bash: cd: usr/bin/python3.7: No such file or directory

Comment: You are missing the leading `/`. It is `/usr/bin/python3.7` not `usr/bin/python3.7`.

Comment: /usr/bin$ cd /python3.7
bash: cd: /python3.7: No such file or directory

Comment: Since now you are in `/usr/bin` you don't need to use `/` before python3.7. Also `python3.7` isn't a directory. So `cd` can't work.

Comment: the leading `/` denotes the top (or root) of the filesystem tree. There is indeed no such file `python3.7` at the top of the hierarchy, however, if your current directory is `/usr/bin`, there may be a file `python3.7` there which you can specify to the shell as `python3.7` (this is a relative path; it is correct from where you are now). But you can't `cd` to a file, so, what are you really trying to do?

Comment: i want to add pyarrow in python dirver by link installing in python3.7driver.but i dont know how do it

Comment: I checked installation and in my system I have pyarrow but when i type import command on python3.7 there was an error tell the pyarrow module isnt there

Comment: It would be better if you ask a question stating exactly what you are trying to do. The answer to this question isn't helping you achieve your goal at all, because messing around with the binary in `/usr/bin` is definitely not going to work to fix your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in a comment from AlexP, you did not include the `/` at the beginning. Even if you did that, you would still not succeed. You are trying to change directory `cd` to a file. Type

```
ls -l /usr/bin/python3.7
```

The output should be something like that

```
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4464400 nov 28  2017 /usr/bin/python3.5
```

For a directory you see a letter `d` at the beginning of the line, like this

```
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 90112 aug  7 06:49 bin
```

You will see, that `python3.7` is a file not a directory. You can change to a directory

```
cd /usr/bin
```

but not to a file like `/usr/bin/python3.7`.

Comment: lenovo@Lenovo-Y50:/usr/bin$ ls -l /usr/bin/python3.7
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 5304720 ژوئن  29 00:01 /usr/bin/python3.7

Comment: -rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4464400 nov 28  2017 /usr/bin/python3.5
-rwxr-xr-x: command not found

Comment: lenovo@Lenovo-Y50:~$ drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 90112 aug  7 06:49 bin
drwxr-xr-x: command not found

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/basic-linux-navigation-and-file-management, https://lowfatlinux.com/linux-directories.html

Comment: Command "/usr/bin/python3.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-l1c30aqp/pyarrow/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-3wjby4o6/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-l1c30aqp/pyarrow/

Comment: -rwxr-xr-x: command not found